# android how to take input in edittext view form start

Tags: android

When i use `style` in my `EditText` starts text input from the middle of `EditText` how  can i change to start character from start of edit textview
if i remove this line is work perfectly take input from start of edit text view

```
 <EditText  
android:id="@+id/txtMobileNo"
android:layout_width="150dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a style for button.

Answer (score 0):

After Understanding you Question, I am sure you have set `android:gravity=Center` to it's parent. Remove the line `android:gravity=Center`  and see the result, is that what you wanted. If not please post your code

Answer (score 0):

Sandra just remove `style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"` from edit text, **because you apply the style of button which has `gravity center` for text.**

```
<EditText  
     android:id="@+id/txtMobileNo"
     android:layout_width="150dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
     android:singleLine="true"/>
```